# Vertical alignment of itemize for larger bullet sizes

Tags: xetex, itemize, awesome-cv

I tried changing the bullet size of the `cvitems` environment using the following code

```
\newenvironment{cvitems}{%
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3ex, nosep, noitemsep]
    \setlength{\parskip}{4pt}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\huge\bullet}
}{%
  \end{itemize}
}
```

This changes the bullet size of each item but as you can see in the following picture, the text is not aligned in the middle.

[image: Text with large bullet]

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the vertical positions of the bullets using `\raisebox{<lenght>}{<text>}`

To use with `awesome-cv` add to the preamble

```
\renewenvironment{cvitems}{%
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3ex, itemsep=4pt, label=\raisebox{-0.55ex}{\huge\textbullet}]% <<<<< changed 
    }{%
    \end{itemize}
}
```

[image: a]

For reference. This is the definition used by `awesome-cv`

```
% Define an environment for cvitems(for cventry)
\newenvironment{cvitems}{%
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
  \begin{justify}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2ex, nosep, noitemsep]
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\bullet}
}{%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{justify}
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
}
```

Notice the negative vertical space added before and after to eliminate blank space.